# Script to SSH to multiple Linux Server and execute a find command

Tags: ssh

I need a script that can SSH to multiple servers and execute a find command to check when was the last time a file was created.

Comment: See parallel-ssh: https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/

Answer (score 0):

If you need it run at the exact same time on all servers, you'll need some form of multi-programming environment. Many languages like Python and Ruby have solutions for that. If you can handle a rapid-fire one-at-a-time thing, just enclose the `ssh` command in a for loop:

```
for server in <list>
do
  ssh $server find ...
done
```

(Note: this loop format works fine for me, but you may need some tweaking depending on your shell.)

Comment: I don't need to run the command at the exact same time. I created the scrip based on tour example but I'm getting this error message: Could not resolve hostname PATH: Name or service now known